# OOP Inventory program

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

The error I'm receiving is an Array index out of bounds exception, but I don't know why it's happening where it is.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inventory
{
    //Maximum amount of objects
    private static int MAX_ITEMS = 100;

    //Iteration from item to item
    private int d_nextItem = 0;

    //Array for the different objects
    private Stock[] d_list  = new Stock[MAX_ITEMS];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
        inventory.loadList(args[0]);
        //Costs printing out,rough draft, toString not made
        System.out.println("COSTS");
        inventory.getTotalCost();
        //Total Selling price printing out
        System.out.println("SELLINGP");
        inventory.getTotalSellingPrice();
        System.out.println("SAMOUNT");
    }
```

The specific error is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Inventory.main(Inventory.java:27) which points towards the inventory.loadList method in main. The error only comes up when run the program, and I don't know why its happening.

This is the loadList method, and the iteration doesn't look wrong, so how is an Array exception happening when the array is storing a reference to the objects information, not all the different strings, int and doubles.

```
  public void loadList(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    fileName = "stock1.txt";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    String newLine = null;
    String name = null;
    String identifier = null;
    int quantity = 0;
    double cost = 0.0;
    double price = 0.0;
            while (input.hasNextLine() && d_nextItem < MAX_ITEMS)
            {
                     if(input.hasNext())
                    {
                            name = input.next();
                    }
                     if(input.hasNext())
                    {
                            identifier = input.next();
                    }
                     if(input.hasNextInt())
                    {
                            quantity = input.nextInt();
                    }
                     if(input.hasNextDouble())
                    {
                            cost = input.nextDouble();
                    }
                     if(input.hasNextDouble())
                    {
                            price = input.nextDouble();
                    }

                    d_list[d_nextItem]= new Stock(name,identifier,quantity,cost,price);
                   newLine = input.nextLine();
                    d_nextItem += 1;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you're not passing a parameter to the program.

`args` is an array containing the parameters passed to the program, the fact that index 0 is out of bounds means there are no parameters.

How exactly to do this would depend on how you're running the program.

Answer (score 0):

The `args[]` array is special in that, when you're using it, you're invoking your program with more info, typically from the command line.

The appropriate way to populate `args[]` would be as follows:

```
java Inventory classname.txt
```

This way, Java will pull `classname.txt` into `args[0]`.

Comment: Wow...........that is what I was doing wrong and I didn't even realize it until I read your comment. And thanks to that I've been able to move on and fix other issues I have. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the code you have pasted here looks fine. So the problem might be elsewhere.
However a couple of quick changes may fix your problem.
use lists instead of an array for stock:
List stocklist = new ArrayList();
stocklist.add(...);

and make d_nextItem a local variable and initialize it before the while loop.

Comment: When this program was assigned to us in class, we hadn't gone into array lists. Right now were currently going over array lists and I'm confident our next assignment will be a variation of this assignment, but using array lists.